# Comando makemigrations no Django (1.9) não reconhece Blank = True num campo boolean

Tags: django-1.9, python-3.x

Eu tenho o seguinte modelo:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    """
    Model for a site entry
    @author: Leonardo Pessoa
    @since: 05/09/2016 
    """
    from decimal import Decimal

    consolidated_financials     = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    type                        = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    tier1_business              = models.ForeignKey(Business, limit_choices_to = {'tier': 1}, related_name='%(class)s_tier1')
```

Note que o campo `consolidated_financials` agora tem o parâmetro `blank=True` que não existia na primeira versão do modelo. Quando eu executo o `makemigrations`, o Django não reconhece a mudança, mas quando adiciono em outro campo que não o `BooleanField`, sim. Existe alguma restrição com este campo em específico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O campo [`BooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield) não toma como parâmetro `null=True`. Ao invés disso, use [`NullBooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#nullbooleanfield).

Tem uma [ótima resposta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/133617) no Programmers.se do Jacob Maristany que diz:

> Se permitir a utilização do null, você está transformando um campo binário (true/false) em ternário (true/false/null), onde suas entradas 'null' são indeterminadas.

Para a discussão completa, veja: [Should I store False as Null in a boolean field database?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/133600)